# ResponseStatusException in Spring 5.3 returning 500 for BAD_REQUEST

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Recently switched from using ControllerAdvice to using the ResponseStatusException which was introduced in Spring 5 but instead of getting a response code that matches the status passed into the ResponseStatusException constructor I am getting a 500 and the message includes the response code.  Any idea what the issue is here?  I can't seem to find anything on SO or online anywhere.  spring-web version is 5.3.9.

Edit: Did some investigation and it looks like the ResponseStatusException is not being handled by the ResponseStatusExceptionHandler.  Any idea why that might be?

Edit 2: Found the cause which was that one of the gradle dependencies was importing a `@ControllerAdvice` annotated class which was catching all exceptions and if it didn't have the specific exception type in a switch case it was treating it as an `INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR`.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(V_1)
public class SpringController {

    @PostMapping(value = /bids, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> postBids(@Valid @RequestBody BidRequest bidRequest) throws JsonProcessingException {

        if (!validateBidRequest(bidRequest)) {
            throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, "Bid request fails validation");
        }

        return ResponseEntity.ok().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).body(response);
    }

    private boolean validateBidRequest(BidRequest bidRequest) {
        return bidRequest.getApplication() != null;
    }
}
```

Response:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2023-11-21T22:25:41.507509Z",
    "id": "13f34470-842c-4a53-8c9d-57186446e301",
    "status": 500,
    "name": "org.springframework.web.server.ResponseStatusException",
    "message": "400 BAD_REQUEST \"Bid request fails validation\""
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you remove the ControllerAdvice class you were using previously?
There is a possibility that the previously used ControllerAdvice class is handling the exception that occurred, or that DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver rather than ResponseStatusExceptionResolver is catching it due to some configuration.

Comment: I did but I ended up finding the issue: one of the gradle dependencies was importing a ControllerAdvice annotated class which caught all exceptions being thrown and converting it to an INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR status.  I'll update my question.

Comment: Oh, thank you for sharing reason of issue!

Answer (score 0):

Found the cause which was that one of the gradle dependencies was importing a @ControllerAdvice annotated class which was catching all exceptions and if it didn't have the specific exception type in a switch case it was treating it as an INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR.  Excluding the class from being used using `@SpringBootApplication(exclude = UnwantedExceptionHandler.class)` fixed the issue